# Is the system $x = 1 + \frac12(\sqrt{4-y^2} - 1)$ and $y = 1 + \frac12(\sqrt{4-x^2} - 1)$ solvable?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Is it possible to solve an exact solution for this system? WolframAlpha has an [exact solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+%3D+1+%2B+%28sqrt%284-y%5E2%29+-+1%29%2F2%2C+y+%3D+1+%2B+%28sqrt%284-x%5E2%29+-+1%29%2F2+solve) but I can't find a way to arrive at it myself.

$$x = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{4-y^2} - 1}{2}$$

$$y = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{4-x^2} - 1}{2}$$

Comment: Of course, but once I've inserted the equation for $y$ into the equation for $x$ I can't figure out how to simplify it much further.

Comment: First of all i would like to see your work on that. Furthermore, if eliminating x gives the above product that you commented, then you just have to find the roots and replace them in order to find $x$ also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those equations can be written as $(2x-1)^2=4-y^2, (2y-1)^2=4-x^2$ after some trivial arithmetic manipulations. Substracting the first from the second we have $$4x^2-4x+y^2=4y^2-4y+x^2$$ or equivalently $$(x-y)(3x-3y-4)=0,$$ which implies that $$(x=y)\lor (x=y+4/3).$$ I hope you can handle the rest.

P.S. I skipped some steps but I guess you can recover them (though this is a good exercise).

Comment: should be $(x-y)(3x+3y-4) = 0 $

Comment: also some solutions are spurious.